# After changing mysql directory, Mysql will no longer start up

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets, debian

I am running a debian machine and I am trying to move my mysql data directory. After looking at a few online tutorials, it looks like the way to do this is changing the datadir in the my.cnf. Some of the tutorials also talk about changing some apparmor files, but it does not look like I have apparmor installed.

After  I changed the my.cnf I would keep on getting the following error in the syslog:

```
Jul 16 16:21:04 sparta /etc/init.d/mysql[29315]:    #007/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
Jul 16 16:21:04 sparta /etc/init.d/mysql[29315]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Jul 16 16:21:04 sparta /etc/init.d/mysql[29315]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

After looking around a little more I came upon a website that said  I should also change the directory for the socket. So I did that, but I still get the same issue.

When I run  `sudo mysqld` start I get the following error:

```
 150716 16:25:54 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150716 16:25:54 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-0+deb7u1) starting as process 29416 ...
150716 16:25:54 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150716 16:25:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
150716 16:25:54 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
150716 16:25:54 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150716 16:25:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150716 16:25:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
150716 16:25:54 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150716 16:25:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150716 16:25:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150716 16:25:54  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Here is a copy of the part of my.cnf file that I edited:

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /mysql_persistant/
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /mysql_persistant/
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
```

I have also chmod 755 the new file directory.

Comment: chown -R mysql:mysql on your mysql data directory?

Comment: I ran that and now sudo mysqld gives me a different error. Im gonna update my question right now.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like the issue was running a chown -R on the directory that I was changing the data too.

It is not necessary to change the location of the socket.